# How can I make my image fit in completely in a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

The image I am applying looks fine in IPhone7 plus simulator and in IPhone 5 simulator it is not like what I want.
I am attaching both the images. Please help me.

[image]

Second image:

[image]

Constraints:

[image]

[image: like this I want two images one over another]

Comment: change imageview's content mode fill to aspectToFit.

Comment: it is not an imageview it is a UIView

Comment: Additionally add , trailing space constraint for that UIView, your problem will solve.

Comment: Instead of giving proportional with, try with giving some static width like 100 and then check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Propotional Constraints instead of giving fix widh , heigth Constraints .**

lets say your View has 250 width & 100 height and you are designing cell in 375 width xib.

Steps of giving Constraints

```
1 :- Leading Constraints  same as you described in your image.
2 :- Center Vertical Constraints same as you described in your image.
3 :- Give aspect Ratio to your View.
4 :- Give equal width Constarint of Your View with Super View.
```

**multiplier Calculation :->  250/375 = 0.6666666667**

Edit the last Constarint which name should like this : **Propotional Width** , edit that Constarint and give multipier as **0.6666666667**

runt the application , if you set proper height of cell with delegate method , it should almost work.

Comment: when i change the UIView with UIimage view the problem solves

Comment: but now the problem is that I have to apply another image over this white circle. How to do that? –

Comment: thats great , but i guess thats not the solution . if you took first UIView and its not work properlly then you can take the help of Debug View Hierarachy .after that you can see its frame and all.

Comment: yeahh I know that is not the solution

Comment: ok no problem  , let me know what exactlly you want ? another imageView over this white circle ? why ?

Comment: yeahh I want another image on this white circle.

Comment: I have attached an image for consultance I want exactly the same as shown in it

Comment: lets first try with older imageView . if its work then you dont need to take another ImageView. just give content mode of imageView like this.
imgView.contentMode = .center   . For this you can directlly set it within .xib file or with coding as well as.

Comment: I did not get u

Comment: you have already one imageView right ? then first create its outlet and then write code like this : imgView.contentMode = .center .  imgView means IBOutlet or object of your older imageView. now getting ?

Comment: for now set any static image to white circle for testing purpose.

Comment: white circle image and the human figure are two separate images that are to be placed one over another

Comment: wait for 5 min only . i will create a demo for you , you can take it from here .

Comment: hello Aashima Anand , have you tried my comment :-> for now set any static image to white circle for testing purpose and give its content mode to .center

Comment: and if you want to take a another ImageView then take it and give a constraint like this .  top , leading , bottom and trailing constraint with older imageView , set corner radius for new imageView and dont forgot to set content mode for new imageView as .center . remove content mode for older imageView

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps:**

1. In your storyboard, use Auto Layouts for UIview like this: Add
   Constraints from left, top, height, width
2. It will work fine for all Screen

Comment: did the same. I have added a screenshot  of constraints

Comment: Try this... Add constraints of View from all four side and add constraints of label and other from top , right,( height and width if you want).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using 7 plus screen resolution in storyboard while designing.
Corner radius applies before your constraints load.

Apply your corner radius in layoutSubviews method after super called.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following constraints for that UIView.

`1. Leading space to its superview 
2. Trailing space to nearest label 
3. Add the constraint Vertically in container 
4. Set Width constraint 
5. Set height constraint.`

Will works perfectly .

Comment: If you set width constraints for all others except UIView, then please remove those constraints..

Comment: it is nothing like that

Comment: when i change the UIView with UIimage view the problem solves

Comment: but now the problem is that I have to apply another image over this white circle. How to do that?

Comment: Follow the above link, so that you can set placeholder image as that white circle ..... It will appears in the case when there is no profile picture ..... If there is profile picture then that  particular profile picture appears,....

Comment: I don't want the white circle to be place holder. Please see the image I attached right now and suggest appropriately

Comment: Ok so at present ,, u are having that white background one as an "imageView with white background" rite.

Comment: To get  circular shape you set cornerRadius for that imageView am, i rite

Comment: the image of circular white background and the human figure in black colour both are separate images

Comment: If so then its simple, as i suggested above ,, make that "dummy man image" as placeholder and what ever image u want as main image,, by using SDWebImage.....Follow the link

Comment: Why u r setting two separate images.Make the background of imageView as White color and then   set ,,,                          
 `imageProfile.layer.cornerRadius = imageProfile.frame.width / 2
 imageProfile.layer.masksToBounds = true....... `                       So that imageView will become as a white circle ...... And after that implement what i said above....